cursor offset while editing code in leetcode.com by edge
one day I find the cursor didn't emege in the right place in my code editor in leetcode.com by microsoft edge, while when I use the chrome to try,the problem vanished. Because I used to use edge as my explorer,and the problem worried me a lot I can't code properly and comfortably.I will appreciate it if you could help me to fix it
this is by edge
this is by chrome
both the picture,my mouse is intended to edit after "s" without blank,but in edge,it can't in the right place
I have tried to reset the layout in the setting of leetcode,but nothing changed,so it maybe the problem of edge,something incompatibility

I tried to reproduce the issue you described on Leetcode.com, but the result was normal in my test on Edge, and the cursor was not behind the blank, as shown in the figure below. I suggest that you should update the version of Edge to the latest version. You can also feedback this problem in the "Discuss" module of Leetcode.com.


thanks, I finally found out the problem came from an extension, after I disable it, the problem vanished.
